# Lost 2 Pokemon on Pokemon X, Where could they be?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

I have recently started up my Nintendo 2DS after about a month of inactivity. I knew for a fact that I had the following 2 pokemon:

- Shiny Gengar (Event Pokemon),
- Vivillon (Event Pokemon, Pokeball pattern)

Is there any place I could have left these pokemon? I have already checked the daycare on route 7 and they aren't there. Is there anywhere else?

Comment: Do you have a Pokebank account?

Comment: Pokebank? And do you miss 2 or 3 Pokemon?

Comment: Traded with a friend? Your evil twin sister 'traded' them by herself?

Comment: Maybe you have "lost" them in your pc, have you tried with the Search option?

Comment: @Mathias711, it was 3 but I think one was from not saving properly. I dont have pokebank. Thanks for the help though

Comment: Have you received them in the first place? If you only entered the code and didn't fetch them from the delivery girl in the pokemon center, she should be standing around and still having them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only places a Pokemon can be are:

- Party
- Day Care
- PC Box
- Pokebank
- Delivery Girl (only if not picked up yet)
- GTS

I assume that if they were in your party, you'd know. You've already checked Day Care and have no Pokebank account, so that rules those out. If you're *sure* you have picked them up from the delivery girl already, then that leaves your PC. Sometimes (especially if you have many caught/bred) it can be hard to locate a specific one in the PC, so try using the search tool as pinckerman suggested in comments.

It's also possible that *one* is in the GTS awaiting a trade. Not likely, since you're missing multiple, but worth mentioning.

Other than that, they could have been released or traded. Assuming you didn't do it, there would be no real way to know this without catching the offender red-handed. If you suspect someone's Pokemon is/was yours (and they will let you look at it), you can see the Original Trainer (OT) name on the summary page.

Comment: Thanks a lot, what happened was: I had claimed the Pokemon from the lady but had forgotten to save. My DS battery must have then died and without thinking about it I assumed the Pokemon had been transferred to my box.